# find #define macros in waf script

Tags: c++, macros, waf

I want to find macro definitions present in my C++ code from my waf build script to be able to adapt my dependencies accordingly to these macros.

As I understand, I should be able to do it using [waflib.Tools.c_preproc.re_mac](https://waf.io/apidocs/tools/c_preproc.html#waflib.Tools.c_preproc.re_mac), however I cannot find any example of its usage.

Comment: Have you tried something with which you would like some help, or are you asking for a pointer to an example?

Comment: I need any example of using re_mac. For now I ended up manually reading cpp files and matching a #define string with count() in python